# How can I return an error or an N/A if an object doesnt exist in the JSON I'm using

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I'm wanting to display who is playing in today's games as well as what channel they are on using this JSON, but it keeps giving me this error:

```
TypeError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/views/results.ejs:8
   6| <% data["games"].forEach(function(game){ %>
   7|     <ul>
>> 8|         <li><%= game["home"]["name"]%> Vs. <%=game["away"]["name"]%> <%=game["broadcast"]["network"][1]%> 
   9|     
   10| 
   11|         </li>

Cannot read property 'network' of undefined
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:524:12), <anonymous>:29:42)
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:524:12), <anonymous>:22:22)
   at returnedFn (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:555:17)
   at tryHandleCache (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:203:34)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:412:10)
   at View.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
   at tryRender (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
   at EventEmitter.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
   at ServerResponse.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)




<h1>Who's Playing Today!</h1>
<h2>Mens NCAA CBB</h2>

<% data["games"].forEach(function(game){ %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= game["home"]["name"]%> Vs. <%=game["away"]["name"]%> <%=game["broadcast"]["network"][1]%> 


        </li>
    </ul>
<% }); %>

<% include partials/footer %>
```

I'm assuming that it is because the object that I am trying to display in my ejs file doesn't exist in some of the JSON sections like below

```
{
    id: "f172b5e1-97d5-4599-a033-fdafeb12de63",
    title: "CBI - First Round - Game 6",
    status: "scheduled",
    coverage: "extended_boxscore",
    scheduled: "2017-03-16T00:05:00+00:00",
    conference_game: false,
    venue: {
        id: "56bfb904-5b8e-4241-bf79-4c02765df0ec",
        name: "Swinney Recreation Center",
        capacity: 2000,
        address: "5030 Holmes St",
        city: "Kansas City",
        state: "MO",
        zip: "64110",
        country: "USA"
    },
    home: {
        name: "UMKC Kangaroos",
        alias: "UMKC",
        id: "820c8f26-cf11-4997-b2e2-19f47bd2f72f"
    },
    away: {
        name: "Green Bay Phoenix",
        alias: "GB",
        id: "61a3e5ab-1be3-4694-b83f-edae0953f409"
    }
}, {
    id: "23ee0924-a55f-4993-a31b-c344f209cd69",
    title: "CBI - First Round - Game 5",
    status: "scheduled",
    coverage: "extended_boxscore",
    scheduled: "2017-03-16T01:00:00+00:00",
    conference_game: false,
    venue: {
        id: "32e70ac7-27f7-4a28-92a4-8584180cf3ca",
        name: "Arena-Auditorium",
        capacity: 15028,
        address: "1000 E University Ave",
        city: "Laramie",
        state: "WY",
        zip: "82071",
        country: "USA"
    },
    home: {
        name: "Wyoming Cowboys",
        alias: "WYO",
        id: "a7127c0a-a466-47ae-91ad-9a71ee2c9427"
    },
    away: {
        name: "Eastern Washington Eagles",
        alias: "EWU",
        id: "54df21af-8f65-42fc-bc01-8bf750856d70"
    }
},
```

Where other times it does have that value:

```
{
    id: "e288ca27-4559-4c41-95d2-de8716baca2f",
    title: "Iowa Bracket - First Round - Game 1",
    status: "scheduled",
    coverage: "full",
    scheduled: "2017-03-16T01:00:00+00:00",
    conference_game: false,
    venue: {
        id: "04c2567a-3a02-462b-b06b-5a4216dd30af",
        name: "Carver-Hawkeye Arena",
        capacity: 15400,
        address: "1 Elliot Drive",
        city: "Iowa City",
        state: "IA",
        zip: "52242",
        country: "USA"
    },
    broadcast: {
        network: "ESPN2",
        satellite: "209",
        internet: "WatchESPN"
    },
    home: {
        name: "Iowa Hawkeyes",
        alias: "IOWA",
        seed: 1,
        id: "c10544de-e3bd-4776-ba2e-83df8c017fd1"
    },
    away: {
        name: "South Dakota Coyotes",
        alias: "SDAK",
        seed: 8,
        id: "c946b7ac-5159-4817-93c4-fc9495c6425b"
    }
}, {
```

Does anyone know how to make it so if it doesn't have that value it will just display N/A and if it does it will actually display the channel it is on?

Comment: `game.hasOwnProperty('network')` will return `false`

Comment: @surajck I'm confused as to how to write this or what to do with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this several ways.

In JSON, explicitly add the properties you are expecting and put N/A in the JSON as string properties.

```
{
...
network: ["N/A"] /* you can change the structure to whatever you need */
...
}
```

If you are not in control of the JSON your javascript can massage the data and add the string `"N/A"` where you need it.

```
let json = fetchJson()
  .map(d => {
    if(!d.broadcast) {
      d.broadcast = {"network": ["N/A"]} // you can put whatever structure you need here
    }
  })
```

Or in your ejs template

```
<li><%= game["home"]["name"]%> Vs. <%=game["away"]["name"]%> <%=(game["broadcast"] ? game["broadcast"]["network"][1] : "N/A")%>
```

Adding the ternary `?` in the ejs template might be the way to go for a drop in solution, but grooming the data prior to template compilation is where I tend to err in my own projects.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you explain what the you mean ternary ? your example works but I want to understand what you did here.

Comment: I just mean the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) It's basically an *inline if statement*

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><%= game["home"]["name"]%> Vs. <%=game["away"]["name"]%> <%=game.hasOwnProperty('network') ? game["broadcast"]["network"][1] : "N/A"%>
```

This will check to see if it has a `broadcast` key, and then if it does, will grab the second network (maybe you want the first? if that's the case use `[0]`), otherwise it will return `N/A`

Comment: This is wrong. `game.hasOwnProperty("network")` returns `true` if  `game.network` exists - **NOT if `game.broadcast.network` exists**.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be simple enough for your purposes:

```
(game.broadcast||{}).network ||"N/A"
```

Used like so:

```
<% data["games"].forEach(function(game){ %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= game["home"]["name"]%> Vs. <%=game["away"]["name"]%> <%=(game.broadcast||{}).network||"N/A"%> 

    </li>
</ul>
```

I noticed that network was a string and not an array, so I assume you did not really want to display just the second letter of it (e.g. `"ESPN"[1] === "S"`)

Comment: You are correct, I didn't want that 1 in there! Thanks for your help!